# How to use tilt in ngx-leaflet?

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have a site in Angular10 where I'm showing a map using ngx-leaflet.
But I cannot make the tilt works.. I need to show the map as a "navigation" view, I mean show the map to the front and not like from the sky as a GPS. So for that I need to set the tilt.
But I cannot find how I can do that.

Below you have my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { icon, latLng, marker, polyline, tileLayer } from 'leaflet';
import { LeafletDirective } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { LocationService } from '../../services/location/location.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './map.component.scss' ]
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  // Define our base layers so we can reference them multiple times
  // Source: https://asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-angular-cli/
  streetMaps = tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    detectRetina: true,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  });
  wMaps = tileLayer('http://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    detectRetina: true,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  });
  @ViewChild(LeafletDirective) leaflet!: LeafletDirective;

  // Set the initial set of displayed layers (we could also use the leafletLayers input binding for this)
  options = {
    layers: [ this.streetMaps, this.route, this.summit, this.paradise ],
    zoom: 16,
    tilt: 90,
    heading: -1,
    center: latLng([ 0, 0 ])
  };

  constructor(private locationService: LocationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onMapReady(event){
    this.locationService.getLocation().subscribe((res: any) => {
      if (res.latitude && res.longitude) {
        event.setView([res.latitude, res.longitude], this.options.zoom, {tilt: 90, heading: -1});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And the view is

```
<div class="map"
     leaflet
     [leafletOptions]="options"
     (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
     [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl">
</div>
```

But it just show the view as a regular GPS, not with an angle like navigation flow.

I followed this example: https://asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-angular-cli/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the leaflet library doesn't support tilt (maybe if someone creates a custom plugin) but rotation is supported...

You can have this to rotate the marker : https://github.com/luks87zg/Leaflet.MovingRotatedMarker

And this to rotate Map:
https://github.com/Raruto/leaflet-rotate

For tilting... you may try Css manipulation